# Insert query executes successfully but data is not inserted to the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm a newbie in php, so if the question is too stupid, please forgive.

I was trying to insert data on a table using mysqli. The query executes successfully and returns the inserted id. But the data is not inserted on the database table.

### Issue causing code:

```
// Creating db connection
$dbObject = new DBHandler();

// Database operations
$query    = "insert into `atmt_status` (taskdate, title, description, User_Id) values (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $dbObject->conn->prepare($query);
if(!$stmt)
{
    die('Problem With Database');
}

$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$taskdate $title, $description, strtolower($userId));
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$insertId = mysqli_insert_id($dbObject->conn);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert('.$insertId.');</script>';
```

This successfully executes and gives the following response:

[image: Inserted ID]

But the data is not inserted on the database table.

### ##What I tried:

#### 1

**Try:**

I replaced the ? with actual values and removed

`$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$taskdate $title, $description, strtolower($userId));`

**Result:**

Successful execution, returned Id: 59, no data inserted in database.

---

#### 2

**Try:**

I checked with

```
mysqli_query($dbObject->conn, $query) or die('Failed to insert');
```

**Result:**

Successful execution, returned Id: 60, no data inserted in database.

---

#### 3

**Try:**

I checked with

```
$dbObject->conn->query($query);
```

**Result:**

Successful execution, returned Id: 61, no data inserted in database.

---

#### 4

**Try:**

Executed the query directly with `MYSQL Querybrowser`

**Result:**

Successful execution, Data inserted to database with ID 62.

---

#### 5

**Try:**

I checked almost all the question in StackOverflow with similar issue, and tried almost all the answers.

**Result:**

Nothing changed, still have the same issue

---

I'm stuck on this issue for last 2 days, I tried many methods but all failed. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us actual query you are executing?

Comment: It looks to be like your data is being successfully inserted. How are you checking whether it was inserted into the database? Is there a possibility that you have two databases and are connecting to a different one then you think you are? Do you have access to something like phpmyadmin to look directly at the database?

Comment: I see two possible reasons: 1) I don't see a commit in your code - if you are not running in auto-commit mode, the changes are not persisted. 2) You see the effects of the `repeatable read` default isolation level in your SQL client that you use to check the data. Run a `commit` or `rollback` in the *client* program prior to checking the data.

Comment: @DamienBlack: yes, I checked it on phpmyadmin and also with mysql query browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed it.

In my code, I set the `autocommit` to `false`, that was the issue:

```
$dbObject->conn,->autocommit(FALSE);
```

I fixed it by changing the above code to:

```
$dbObject->conn,->autocommit(TRUE);
```

Thanks for [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), his below comment helped me to find the issue.

> I see two possible reasons: 1) I don't see a commit in your code - if
>   you are not running in auto-commit mode, the changes are not
>   persisted. 2) You see the effects of the repeatable read default
>   isolation level in your SQL client that you use to check the data. Run
>   a commit or rollback in the client program prior to checking the data.
>   – a_horse_with_no_name